# XSLT Add Headers When Row Variable Changes

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, row

We have a Python script that generates a report of XML output similar to this:

```
<ROOT>
  <results3>
    <ROW **TicketNumber="CHG000000061374"** Env=" " CustomerProject="MCI-Sacramento"     Program="Infrastructure" Summary="INFRA - Bi-Weekly Sac Portal Maintenance - SACPORTAL2"  ImplementorGroup="Database Management" Implementor="Juan "/>
    <ROW **TicketNumber="CHG000000061374"** Env=" " CustomerProject="MCI-Sacramento" Program="Infrastructure" Summary="INFRA - Bi-Weekly Sac Portal Maintenance - SACPORTAL2"  ImplementorGroup="Database Management" Implementor="Malcolm"/>
    <ROW **TicketNumber="CHG000000061374"** Env=" " CustomerProject="MCI-Sacramento" Program="Infrastructure" Summary="INFRA - Bi-Weekly Sac Portal Maintenance - SACPORTAL2" ImplementorGroup="Incident Support-OSSC" Implementor="Amar"/>
    <ROW **TicketNumber="CHG000000061375"** Env=" " CustomerProject="Verizon-KOVR" Program="Operations - SAC" Summary="INFRA - Server decom - see description" ImplementorGroup="Operations - SAC" Implementor="Ralph"/>
    <ROW **TicketNumber="CHG000000061375"** Env=" " CustomerProject="Verizon-KOVR" Program="Operations - SAC" Summary="INFRA - Server decom - see description" ImplementorGroup="Operations - SAC" Implementor="Ralph"/>
```

The XML is then transformed into HTML.

When the TicketNumber variable changes I'd like to add a Header row or add a blank row or change the formatting so that the user can easily see all the info for one ticket grouped together. Otherwise it runs altogether.  Is there a way to do this in XSLT?

Comment: If you're in XSLT 2.0, use xsl:for-each-group/@group-adjacent. (I imagine you're probably not in XSLT 2.0, if you were, you wouldn't need to ask the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="results3">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <xsl:if test="@TicketNumber != preceding-sibling::ROW[1]/@TicketNumber">
      <tr>Header</tr>
    </xsl:if>
      <tr>
       <xsl:attribute name="id" select="@TicketNumber"/>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the adjusted input from your example (removed the **) generates the output

```
<table>
 <tr id="CHG000000061374"></tr>
 <tr id="CHG000000061374"></tr>
 <tr id="CHG000000061374"></tr>
 <tr>Header</tr>
 <tr id="CHG000000061375"></tr>
 <tr id="CHG000000061375"></tr>
</table>
```

The template matching `ROW` checks if the Ticketnumber of the current row is different from the Ticketnumber of the previous/preceding row - `@TicketNumber != preceding-sibling::ROW[1]/@TicketNumber` - and adds a header row in this case.

Comment: Matthias, just got it working. One last question: How would I get the header row to display as the first row?

Comment: Think I solved it - used this code:                 <!-- Select column names only once -->
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                        <tr class="header">
                        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                            <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                </xsl:if>